# How to prevent my app from crashing when handling any error?

Tags: java, android, error-handling

I use a `OnClickListener` to execute a method this way :

```
    b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (on){
                try {sendData("b");} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            }
            else {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You should turn bluetooth on!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
        }
    });
```

`sendData` method :

```
public void sendData(String s) throws IOException {
    try {
        byte[] byteString = s.getBytes();
        outputStream.write(byteString);
        outputStream.flush();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s + "sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s + "not sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

this makes my app crashes if `on = true`

> 03-28 08:37:09.733 28841-28841/com.android.map.brasrobotique
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                  Process: com.android.map.brasrobotique, PID: 28841
>                                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.map.brasrobotique.MainActivity.sendData(MainActivity.java:221)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.map.brasrobotique.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:77)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
>                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19270)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
>                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

how to prevent it from exiting?

thank you!

Comment: Post Error log please

Comment: You should read about `nested try-catch` . Also add crash logs if you need any help .

Comment: I forgot to add it, sorry!

Comment: instead of IOException , use Exception. You are not catching Null pointer Exception.

Comment: You should post that as an answer, Jyoti so then you get 15 points!

Comment: @JyotiJK thank you SO much!!! this saved my day!!!

Comment: Happy to help you!!! And also remove try catch in your onclick since the exception will be caught in the method itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just catching `IOException`s. Catch any `Exception` and it should work. I suspect that your `outputStream` is null.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
b= (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (on){
                    try {sendData("b");} catch (IOException | NullPointerException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                }
                else {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You should turn bluetooth on!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
            }
        });
```

This will catch `NullPointerException` and `IOException`